# Wordpress in "Couch Mode"?

Tags: customization, rewrite-rules

I am trying to setup a "Couch Mode" (distraction free reading) on my WordPress blog as laid out in [this article](http://www.labnol.org/internet/wordpress-reading-experience/19845/).

The guide in the article follows these steps:

1. Create a new page in WordPress with slug `read`
2. Add the following rewrite rule at the top of the *.htaccess* file:

   `RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 [QSA,L]`
3. Save [this file](https://gist.github.com/eanurag/5295092) as *page-read.php*
4. Add this link to to single.php of my theme using `<?php the_ID(); ?>`

I did everything as per the article but when I click the "Read story without the clutter" link on my posts it throws an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /read/761/ was not found on this server.

My local development wordpress installation is: `localhost/techylab/`

While the post where I am trying this Couch Mode is: `localhost/techylab/761/something`

Comment: If you're getting your server's 404, that means you got your rewrite rule wrong. That article is a bad example of how to accomplish this, try looking around this site for some examples using [add_rewrite_endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

Comment: @Milo Sorry to say but I am not able to figure out what's wrong with the rewrite rule here. I do not know much about them.

RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 [QSA,L]

Also FYI when I am opening the page with "read" slug, it opens with new page template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method to achieve what you want internally without adding anything to the .htaccess file.

It works by [adding a rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) named `read`, so any single post permalink with `read` appended to the end will have a different single post template applied.

For example, if your normal single post permalink is:

```
localhost/techylab/some-post-title/
```

The alternate version will be available at:

```
localhost/techylab/some-post-title/read/
```

**First**, add the rewrite endpoint. This goes in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpa_read_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'read', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_read_endpoint' );
```

After adding this, visit your permalinks settings page in admin to flush the rewrite rules so this endpoint will be added to the rules.

**Next**, [filter the single post template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filter_Reference/type_template) and check for the presence of the `read` query var. If it exists, load the template within the theme folder named `read.php`. This is your simplified post template with whatever markup and template tags you want. The correct post has already been queried, so no need for a special query to load the post via the ID as in the version you posted, the normal loop will work just like in any other template.

```
function wpa_read_template( $template = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( ! array_key_exists( 'read', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) return $template;

    $template = locate_template( 'read.php' );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_read_template' );
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to suggest an alternate for this. But I have some confusions:
1. I added the rewrite endpoint in `functions.php` and flushed the rewrite rules. Now would my .htaccess file contain any extra rules in it? Other than the usual default of Wordpress?

2. What do you mean by **check the presence of `read` query?** Did you mean `<?php the_content('Read more &raquo;'); ?>` ?

3. The code that you had mentioned at the end, where will this go in my `single.php` ? I mean I will still need to give a hyperlink like `localhost/techylab/something/read` right?

Comment: WordPress has its own internal rewrites, which this is a part of, so you won't see anything change in .htaccess. No changes to that file are needed for this to work. The second bit of code is what is checking if `read` exists in the request, that also goes in your `functions.php` file. It's hooked to a filter that runs when WordPress is loading the template for a single post, and overrides the normal template selection to load your special template. You will still need to manually append `/read/` to the end of any post permalink you want viewed via your `read.php` template.

Comment: thanks for the clarification again. I did exactly as told. Now when I am manually appending `/read/` to the end of any single post url, it is being redirected to the post with id = 1 (usually `Hello World`). Am I missing something here again?

Comment: it's difficult to say what's going on. if you visited the permalinks page after updating, it should work as-is. I've pasted this straight into an unedited twenty twelve theme with no plugins and it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: You mean with the same template https://gist.github.com/eanurag/5295092 as I mentioned in the question? I don't know what's going wrong here :|

Comment: I just duplicated single.php and renamed it. the query and custom loop in the template you linked is not necessary with this method, as WordPress already does the query automatically before the template is loaded, you just need the default vanilla loop.

Comment: That is working then @Milo :) Thanks a ton ! No query or custom loop need in template !