# Custom post type templating problem

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, advanced-taxonomy-queries, template-hierarchy

I have a custom post type named 'product', with taxonomies 'brand' and 'type'.

I'd like to have Archive Page A:

- sidebar with all the 'brand' terms linking to their respective archive page
- list of all the products that belong to the term.

I'd like to have Archive Page B:

- sidebar with all the 'type' terms linking to their respective archive page
- list of all the products that belong to the term.

When I click on a permalink of a product on Archive Page A, it should direct me to Single Page A

- sidebar with all the 'brand' terms linking to their respective archive page
- content of the product

And similarly when I click on a product link on Archive Page B, it should direct me to Single Page B

- sidebar with all the 'type' terms linking to their respective archive page
- content of the product

How do I achieve this result in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive pages A & B already exist as your brand and type term archives, you can style those differently by creating `taxonomy-brand.php` and `taxonomy-type.php` templates.

The remaining piece is two different single product views. The simplest way to achieve that would be to append a GET var onto the permalinks:

```
http://domain.com/product/someproduct/?origin=brand
http://domain.com/product/someproduct/?origin=type
```

WordPress has the built in function [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to help add that for you:

```
echo add_query_arg( 'origin', 'brand', get_permalink() );
```

Then in your single post template you can check the value of `$_GET['origin']` to determine what to display in the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I managed to solve it this way. Is there a way to remove the GET variable from the URL? Can I at least hide it somehow? Or is there another superglobal I could use that is invisible?

Comment: the issue is that you are dealing with separate http requests, so you have to persist the data between the requests. that means either `GET`, `POST`, cookie, or session. Cookies and sessions will be per-user, so will be much less performant and break if you want to employ caching. Your other option is to [add rewrite endpoints](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) which will make the URLs look a bit nicer, like `http://domain.com/product/someproduct/type/` and `http://domain.com/product/someproduct/brand/` or `http://domain.com/product/someproduct/origin/type/`

Comment: I've read the documentation but can't figure out how to actually implement that fucntion. Could you please help?

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94365/4771) shows an example of adding a rewrite endpoint and loading a different template.