# Create Subfolder that always displays template file

Tags: directory

We have multiple magazine titles on our website and I'm looking to code subdirectories to show certain info.  For example:

- website.com/title1/pdf
- website.com/title2/pdf
- website.com/title3/pdf

The 'title' page contains custom fields with additional info (in this case the url to a pdf file)... I want Wordpress to understand that if someone tried to go to ANY subdirectory (in this case) named 'pdf' that it will fire a particular template file (that handles displaying the information).

The key is that I need to be able to know that is a 'child' of the title so that I can get the correct data points... but I also might just be able to look at the url and grab the title's slug to get that info.

Comment: Have you tried something where we can help you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... I'll have no problem writing the code to actually handle it, I just have no idea how to get wordpress to trigger a particular file based on a subdirectory name.

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94365/4771).

Comment: I meant that "I need this and also be able to do this" is not a good question format; you should show us what you have tried or at least what you have investigated. Sorry if I was rude, it was not my intention. The answer linked by Milo is what I had in mind for this question. Try it and let us know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks, no worries.  Milo's post has me on the right track, but so far not working. it's in the functions of the child theme... is that correct?  Then, here is the code I have `function wpa_read_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'pdf', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa_read_endpoint' );

function wpa_read_template( $template = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( ! array_key_exists( 'pdf', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) return $template;

    $template = locate_template( 'pdfPage.php' );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_read_template' );`

Comment: Sorry, don't know why the code is reading like that.  Anyway, when I test, it gives me a 404. http://dev.eregulations.com/florida/fishing/pdf/

Comment: I got it... 1. I had added | EP_PAGES in the endpoint rewrite and needed to go back to the permalink settings to reset, and 2. I needed to change 'single_template' to 'page_template' as I am using pages... Works like a champ!  Thanks so much for your help, Milo and cybmeta.