# How can I relate custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I've got a custom post type of product and one of case study.

Each product has a series of related case studies. How in Wordpress can I relate these items?

I'm using CMB2 and a custom multiselect field that allows the user to select the related product for a case study. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Also the page that lists all the case studies for a particular product is very much like an archive page so it would be nice to be able to access it via

/productname/casestudies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to handle this. I would store the parent product ID for each case study as post meta data for the case study. You can then use a [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to get all case studies for a product. To display the case studies archive page, [add a rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to generate the `/productname/casestudies` rewrite rules. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94365/4771) for how to load a different template for those requests.