# Two different layouts for the same post

Tags: pages

I'm making a newspaper, and I want to have two different options for viewing posts: "web" (for viewing with laptop, smartphone, etc.) and "billboard" (dynamically cycles through the content; meant for a TV display in our lobby). These are two completely different HTML layouts.

The way I currently have it is very messy; all the code is in one `single-newspaper.php` file and there is an if-statement to check which viewing option (query var) before any HTML.

Although it works, it is a really ugly way of doing it, and I was wondering if there are any neater options. I'd like to have something like:

- `single-newspaper.php`: Checks the viewing option and displays either:
- `newspaper/newspaper_web.php`: For web viewing
- `newspaper/newspaper_tv.php`: TV mode

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94261/wordpress-in-couch-mode/94365), similar problem / solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the viewing option in `single-newspaper.php`, and then use [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) to load the appropriate template part.